# How to UrlEncodedFormEntity to MultipartEntityBuilder and not get a 403?

Tags: java, android, json, http, post

How can I encode a MultipartEntityBuilder instead of using a separate method?

I've tried multiple ways but keep getting a 403 status code.
This is an example:

```
private void doPost(int type) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://amazon.com");
    post.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");

    if(type == 1)
        post.setEntity(useBuilder());
    else if(type == 2)
        post.setEntity(useEncoder()); //<---- wanting to not have to do this
}

private HttpEntity useBuilder(){
    MultipartEntityBuilder me = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    me.addTextBody("name1", "value1");
    me.addTextBody("name2", "value2");
    return me.build();
}

private UrlEncodedFormEntity useEncoder() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name1", "value1"));
    list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name2", "value2"));
    return new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list, "UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

Comment: I will not follow that link. You were supposed to tell what the error means. Then apply it to your code/problem. Answering in this way will not bring you further.